# is RhoMobile support developiong background services for mobile applications?

Tags: mobile-application, rhomobile, rhodes, background-service

is RhoMobile support developiong background services for mobile applications? Is it possible to develop a service that always work in background and take care of something especial? If yes, is that service works fine on all supported platforms?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a completely different application interacting with a rho-mobile application and manipulate data with it.

See [RhoMobile Synchronization](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.1.0/guide/using_rhoconnect)